# SWI-Prolog: ERROR: Undefined procedure: martial_status/2

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to make a simple decision tree answering question in Prolog. I do confess some of this syntax I don't fully understand, but from what I do understand, I think my program should be working. The code is below. Whenever I run it, I get multiple errors. The full list of `ERRORs` I get are as follows:

```
ERROR: Undefined procedure: martial_status/2
ERROR:   However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         marital_status/2
ERROR: 
ERROR: In:
ERROR:   [13] martial_status(_5306,_5308)
ERROR:   [12] not(user:martial_status(_5342,_5344)) at c:/program files/swipl/boot/init.pl:346
ERROR:   [11] ask_marital_status(_5368,_5370) at c:/users/itsar/onedrive/documents/prolog/decision-tree.pl:9
ERROR:   [10] stable_risk(_5394) at c:/users/itsar/onedrive/documents/prolog/decision-tree.pl:20
ERROR:    [9] invest(_5418,oil) at c:/users/itsar/onedrive/documents/prolog/decision-tree.pl:24
ERROR:    [8] main(_5444,oil) at c:/users/itsar/onedrive/documents/prolog/decision-tree.pl:6
ERROR:    [7] <user>
```

The first three lines seem to be self-contradictory, saying `marital_status/2` is not defined but also is defined. I have Schrödinger's procedure I guess. Any help?

```
marital_status(joe,married).
income(joe,60000).
mortgage(joe,20000).
age(joe,45).

main(X,Z):-var(X), write('what is your name?'),read(X), invest(X,Z),!.
main(X,Z):-invest(X,Z),!.

ask_marital_status(X,Y):-marital_status(X,Y).
ask_marital_status(X,Y):-
   not(martial_status(X,Y)),
   write('what is your marital status: married or single?'),
   read(Y), nl,
   asserta(marital_status(X,Y)).

ask_income(X,Y):-income(X,Y).
ask_income(X,Y):-
   not(income(X,Y)),
   write('what is your annual income?'), nl,
   read(Y),
   asserta(income(X,Y)).

ask_mortgage(X,Z):-mortgage(X,Z).
ask_mortgage(X,Z):-
   not(mortgage(X,Z)),
   write('what is your mortgage?'),
   read(Z), nl,
   asserta(mortgage(X,Z)).

ask_age(X,A):-age(X,A).
ask_age(X,A):-
   not(age(X,A)),
   write('what is your age?'),
   read(A),
   nl,
   asserta(age(X,A)).

moderate_risk(X):-
   ask_marital_status(X,Y), Y=married,
   ask_income(X,I), I=<50000,
   ask_mortgage(X,Z), Z=<50000,!.
moderate_risk(X):-
   ask_marital_status(X,M), M=married,
   ask_income(X,I), I=<50000,!.
moderate_risk(X):-
   ask_marital_status(X,M), M=single,
   ask_income(X,I), I=<35000,!.

stable_risk(X):-
   ask_marital_status(X,M), M=married,
   ask_income(X,I), I=<50000,
   ask_mortgage(X,Z), Z>50000,!.
stable_risk(X):-
   ask_marital_status(X,M), M=single,
   ask_income(X,I), I>35000,
   ask_age(X,A), A>50, !.

high_risk(X):-
   ask_marital_status(X,M), M=single,
   ask_income(X,I), I>35000,
   ask_age(X,A), A=<50, !.

invest(X,oil):-stable_risk(X),!.
invest(X,telecommunications):-moderate_risk(X),!.
invest(X,computers):-high_risk(X),!.
```

Comment: Can you clean up your posting of the ERROR?  Your commentary seems to be mixed into it.

Comment: [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)!

Comment: Thank you @false for cleaning up the formatting. I'm new-ish to Stack Overflow and definitely new to Prolog.

Comment: The error is quite clear: you defined a `marital_status/2` predicate but you're calling instead `martial_status/2`. A simply typo.

Comment: `martial_status/2` sounds better than `marital_status/2`. Prepare a boarding party! Anyway, the toplevel already comes with [DWIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM) support ... are there any linters which would catch such errors?

Comment: @David: No error, it's the same.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Yes, the Logtalk linter would have printed a warning that the predicate `martial_status/2` was called but nor defined or declared (assuming the code encapsulated in an object or a module).

Comment: @false the problem here seems to be a typo. normally this question should be closed as "simple typo". there's already one close vote on it as you can see. I don't understand this bounty. the purer solution to what problem?

Comment: @Will: A purer solution to the actual program - not the syntax errors. All this read-code.